# Displaying item duplicates in a List<> shopping basket c#

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, console.writeline

I have a program that allows the user to buy items and it places each item in a List. This is the shopping basket. I want the program to also display their receipt. However if the user buys a lot of items then just listing out their basket will make the receipt too long. So I tried to display the duplicate items in the list:

```
static void generateReceipt(List<string> basket)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < basket.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(basket.Count(x => x == basket[i]) + "x ................ " + basket[i]);
        }

    }
```

However when I run this with, let's say 5 duplicate 'cake' in the basket the output will look like:

5x ............. cake

5x ............. cake

5x ............. cake

5x ............. cake

5x ............. cake

How would I get my function to just display a single "5x .......... cake"? What am I missing?

Comment: You run your loop 5 times (basket.Count() times) so how it can output just 1 line?

Comment: @Evk but there could be multiple items in the basket. What way would I check so that this doesn't repeat?

Comment: See the provided answers (use `GroupBy`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 static void generateReceipt(List<string> basket)
 {
        foreach(var item in basket.Distinct())
        {
          Console.WriteLine(basket.Count(x => x == item) + "x ................ " + item);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Works, but is considerably slower than `GroupBy` (O(N^2) vs. O(N))

Answer (score 1):

Use `GroupBy`.

```
foreach (var group in basket.GroupBy( x => x ) )
    Console.WriteLine( $"{group.Count()}x {group.Key}" );
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution here is to use `GroupBy`:

```
void Main()
{
    var basket = new List<string>
    {
        "Cake",
        "Cake",
        "Apples",
        "Bananas",
        "Cake",
        "Cookies",
        "Cake"
    };

    GenerateReceipt(basket);

    // Output:
    // 4x ................ Cake
    // 1x ................ Apples
    // 1x ................ Bananas
    // 1x ................ Cookies
}

static void GenerateReceipt(List<string> basket) {
    var groupedBasket = basket.GroupBy(b => b);

    foreach (var item in groupedBasket) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Count()}x ................ {item.Key}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks I think I need to look up what GroupBy actually does though...

Comment: Essentially it provides you with the distinct (non-duplicate) elements in the collection, and then you can use `Count` to give you the number of times that element was present.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to find distinct items and count dublicated for each item. You can use "group by" operator for finding them. For example:

```
 static void generateReceipt(List<string> basket)
        {
            var itemsGroupped = from item in basket
                                  group item by item into g
            select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

            foreach (var item in itemsGroupped)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Count + "x ................ " + item.Name);
            }

        }
```